# QGIS model designer, get output value

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am developing a model, will go through different steps of calculation to create new field using @field calculator algorithm which can generate a layer as output.
.
One of my calculations is to generate a serial number because this model will be running more than one time for each try, and i want to track my results. this value will by an input from another Expression  = rand( 100000000000,999999999999)

[image]

The issue is I can't get that value for the serial number produced by Expression and will create temporary layer named serial_number_layer, to use that value again in Atlas exporting filter.
I tried to use attribute, aggregate, use the output directly for both Expression  or field calculator.
.

How do I get that serial number attribute value?